# Rails 5.2 Net::SMTPAuthenticationError - 535 Authentication failed: account disabled When Sending Email (Localhost and Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid

I'm trying to get a Rails 5.2 mailer working, but am coming across a `Net::SMTPAuthenticationError - 535 Authentication failed: account disabled` error on both `localhost` and my Heroku `production` environment.

The mailer looks like this:

```
class AdminNotificationsMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: "liz@linchpinindustries.com"

  def new_rfp(rfp)
    @rfp = rfp
    mail(
      :to => "liz@linchpinindustries.com",
      :subject => 'New RFP Alert!'
    )
  end

  def new_contact_us(contact)
    @contact = contact
    mail(
      to: "liz@linchpinindustries.com",
      subject: 'New Contact Us Submission on LPI'
    )
  end

end
```

With the trigger in my `rfp#create action` (for the first mailer, the `new_rfp` one):

```
def create
    @rfp = Rfp.new(rfp_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @rfp.save!
        AdminNotificationsMailer.new_rfp(@rfp).deliver
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: "Thanks for your request!  We'll get back to you ASAP.  Stay tuned!" }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @rfp }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @rfp.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I have provisioned Sendgrid and double checked my username and password with `puts` (it is correct on localhost and production).

I have the following in my `environment.rb`:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :user_name => ENV["SENDGRID_USERNAME"],
  :password => ENV["SENDGRID_PASSWORD"],
  :domain => 'linchpinindustries.com',
  :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port => 587,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

I've consulted posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28472490/rails-netsmtpauthenticationerror-535-authentication-failed-bad-username) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30226176/ruby-on-rails-bad-username-password-535-auth-failed/30227214), but nothing is working.

I'm officially stumped.  Can anyone see why this error is occurring?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Everything in your settings looks correct so is this not just as simple as

```
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError - 535 Authentication failed: account disabled
```

your account is for whatever reason `disabled`.  Check with Sendgrid that your account is up and running correctly.

Comment: For some reason I had to delete and reprovision the addon...but I wasn't allowed to re-add it at first because my account had been red flagged.  I contacted support and they said it was clearly a "false positive" situation, apologized, and reactivated my account.  So bizarre, but it works now!

Comment: This is correct, @Liz most of the time when an account is sleeping for a while, the red flag it.

Answer (score 5):

I was getting a similar error message, and the problem was that I turned on 2FA authentication on my sendgrid, and didn't realize I had to update my configuration in the app when I did that.

Now, instead of a custom username and password, you have to provide `username = "apikey"` and password is your api key

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  domain: 'YOUR_DOMAIN.COM',
  address:        "smtp.sendgrid.net",
  port:            587,
  authentication: :plain,
  user_name:      'apikey',
  password:       ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY']
}
```

[This post helped me find the solution.](https://medium.com/le-wagon/how-to-send-email-with-action-mailer-and-sendgrid-in-rails-5-32ed0c9167fd)

Answer (score 0):

Can you test this configuration? It's working on my project.

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
    :port => 465,
    :domain => "vibol.xyz",
    :ssl => true,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :authentication => :login,
    :user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD']
  }
```

Comment: I remember I had some issue (but cannot remember detail), and after spending lots of time testing I get it working by using above configuration.

Comment: I tried this and everything went through, it had no errors, the server showed the email was sent, but the email still never arrived!  (Yes, I checked spam.)

Comment: It's in my `rfp#create` method:  `AdminNotificationsMailer.new_rfp(@rfp).deliver`.